# Using Column names as a parameter of POINT geometry in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on a query which fetches all the rows in which lat and longs are inside given polygon.
I am using geometry functions to do so.
I am able to use contain method with polygon and point, However In my case I am using polygon coordinates explicitly in query and want to use "latitude" and "longitude" column name as parameters of POINT. I tried to use concat method but I am getting a "false" return from contain method.

query:

```
  SELECT 
    * 
  from table  
  WHERE 
    contains(
       GeomFromText(
         'POLYGON(
            (32.717399 -117.144126,32.714655  -117.136487,32.710827 -117.145843,32.714005 -117.146444, 32.717399 -117.144126))
         '),
       GeomFromText(
         'POINT(
            concate(latitude," ",longitude))
         '))
```

My table structure is:

```
property_id                 int(11)
latitude                    decimal(10,6)    
longitude                   decimal(10,6)
Address_f1365               char(100)
AddressOnTheInternet_f27    char(255)
```

Comment: pls tell us the table structure

Comment: table structure is like this:                                               property_id int(11) 
latitude decimal(10,6)   
longitude decimal(10,6)
Address_f1365 char(100)
AddressOnTheInternet_f27 char(255)

Comment: Show structure in the post, not in comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this, before using in actual query:

```
SELECT asWKT(GeomFromText(CONCAT('POINT(', 15, ' ', 26, ')')));
```

Shows:

```
'POINT(15 26)'
```

I suggest you to test anything, that would be part of spatial data query with function `asWKT()` / `asText()`. Check the **manual** for [supported formats](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/supported-spatial-data-formats.html) and [conversion functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/functions-to-convert-geometries-between-formats.html).

You have wrongly used `CONCAT()`. Try:

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM
    `table`
WHERE 
    CONTAINS(
       GeomFromText('POLYGON((32.717399 -117.144126,32.714655  -117.136487,32.710827 -117.145843,32.714005 -117.146444, 32.717399 -117.144126))')
    ,
       GeomFromText(CONCAT('POINT(', latitude, ' ', longitude, ')'))
    )
```

Comment: I tried both the queries its not working. I think concat is resulting lat and long to single string and POINT is giving wrong output.

Comment: @techrahul87 Try `SELECT CONCAT('POINT(', latitude, ' ', longitude, ')') FROM table`. Results is correct WKT?

Comment: @techrahul87 You might also try `SELECT asWKT(GeomFromText(CONCAT('POINT(', latitude, ' ', longitude, ')'))) FROM table;`. It should show you correct WKT, or false on failure (fro each row of your table).

Comment: Well Thanks a lot CORRUPT. this was really worked like a charm. Yes I was not using concat correctly. :-)

Comment: @techrahul87 Spatial extension is challenging one. I wish you luck with your tasks.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution

```
SELECT  longitud, latitud, st_distance_sphere(POINT(-78.4865491, -0.1373272), POINT( CAST(longitud as DECIMAL(12,10)) , CAST(latitud as DECIMAL(12,10)) )) as dist from cb_aliados
```